# google maps v3 is displayed on the screen, but disappears in a moment

Tags: javascript, java, android, html, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to display google map on my Hybrid Android App.

In HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/map.css" >
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MyApiKey&sensor=true"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var map;
        function initialize() {
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(38.909401, -77.030304);
            var opts = {
                zoom: 15,
                center: latlng,
                mapTypeControl: false,
                zoomControl: false,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("routeMap"), opts);
        }
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="routeMap"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

And in css,

```
#routeMap {
    height:100%;
}
```

I call the first HTML through Webview.

```
WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.routeMapView);
webView .getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView .loadUrl("file:///android_asset/html/map.html");
```

By the above codes, google map displays on screen(working through an emulator in eclipse).
But in a moment, the map disappears and this screen becomes blank.
Does anybody see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve using             WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.routeMapView);

Comment: I'd like to displays map on Webview area.

Comment: Thank you everyone.
It's because of my mistake, specifying a incorrect referrer.
Sorry.